# Error:java: error: release version 12 not supported

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm trying to compile my h.w. program and getting this error:

[image: build error and info messages]

here is my settings:

[image: settings]

I also tried to press on the '+' on the right, there is just one option, and try to compile with the settings:

[image: settings2]

project structure:

[image]

project directory:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log in your first image, it seems like you are compiling with JDK 11.
You can select the Project SDK in Project Settings -> Project. Make sure this matches with your required version.

Comment: but I don't have version 12 in the dir

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the obvious. thank you, it worked

Comment: when you say "required version" what exactly are you referencing? @PieterjanDeconinck